# C# DataGridView cannot relocate column after HScroll immediately

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

C# DataGridView cannot relocate column after HScroll immediately.
As above, is there any solution? I think this is a BUG.
I have look at the sourcecode of DataGridView below,And I found it doesn't go to "BeginColumnRelocation" after I scroll.

```
        protected virtual void OnCellMouseMove(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= this.Columns.Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("e.ColumnIndex");
            }
            if (e.RowIndex >= this.Rows.Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("e.RowIndex");
            }
            DataGridViewCell dataGridViewCell = GetCellInternal(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
            Debug.Assert(dataGridViewCell != null);
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridViewCell.MouseMoveUnsharesRowInternal(e))
            {
                DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = this.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                GetCellInternal(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).OnMouseMoveInternal(e);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridViewCell.OnMouseMoveInternal(e);
            }

            DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler eh = this.Events[EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLMOUSEMOVE] as DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler;
            if (eh != null && !this.dataGridViewOper[DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_inDispose] && !this.IsDisposed)
            {
                eh(this, e);
            }

            if (!this.dataGridViewState1[DATAGRIDVIEWSTATE1_scrolledSinceMouseDown] &&
                !this.dataGridViewOper[DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_trackColResize] &&
                !this.dataGridViewOper[DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_trackRowResize] &&
                !this.dataGridViewOper[DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_trackColRelocation] &&
                !this.dataGridViewOper[DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_trackColHeadersResize] &&
                !this.dataGridViewOper[DATAGRIDVIEWOPER_trackRowHeadersResize] &&
                this.AllowUserToOrderColumns &&
                this.SelectionMode != DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect &&
                this.SelectionMode != DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect &&
                e.Button == MouseButtons.Left &&
                this.ptMouseDownCell.Y == -1 &&
                this.ptMouseDownCell.X >= 0 &&
                this.ptMouseDownCell.X < this.Columns.Count)
            {
                Point ptGridCoord = ConvertCellToGridCoord(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, e.X, e.Y);

                HitTestInfo hti = HitTest(ptGridCoord.X, ptGridCoord.Y);

                Debug.Assert(hti.Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.None &&
                             hti.Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.HorizontalScrollBar &&
                             hti.Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.VerticalScrollBar);

                switch (hti.typeInternal)
                {
                    // Check for column header mouse down
                    case DataGridViewHitTestTypeInternal.ColumnHeader:
                    case DataGridViewHitTestTypeInternal.ColumnHeaderLeft:
                    case DataGridViewHitTestTypeInternal.ColumnHeaderRight:
                    case DataGridViewHitTestTypeInternal.FirstColumnHeaderLeft:
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(!this.dataGridViewState2[DATAGRIDVIEWSTATE2_messageFromEditingCtrls]);
                        if (Math.Abs(this.ptMouseDownGridCoord.X - ptGridCoord.X) >= DataGridView.DragSize.Width ||
                            Math.Abs(this.ptMouseDownGridCoord.Y - ptGridCoord.Y) >= DataGridView.DragSize.Height)
                        {
                            BeginColumnRelocation(this.ptMouseDownGridCoord.X, this.ptMouseDownCell.X);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what u want to do wather u awant to fix the column or u want to move the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to move the column, and I found the solution, just override OnMouseDown and change the the private field.

```
    private static FieldInfo _dataGridViewState1FieldInfo = null;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dataGridViewState1FieldInfo == null)
        {
            var type = typeof (DataGridView);
            var bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                            | BindingFlags.Static;
            _dataGridViewState1FieldInfo = type.GetField("dataGridViewState1", bindFlags);
        }

        if (_dataGridViewState1FieldInfo != null)
        {
            BitVector32 bits = (BitVector32) _dataGridViewState1FieldInfo.GetValue(this);
            if (bits[0x00000800])
            {
                bits[0x00000800] = false;
                _dataGridViewState1FieldInfo.SetValue(this, bits);
            }
        }

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
```